# phpmyadmin has no installation candidate

Tags: 19.10, lamp, phpmyadmin, php7

I have updated and addded repositories to my sources list, but it still doesn't work:

```
cyan@cyanonvo:~$ sudo apt install phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for cyan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, it has been obsoleted, or   
is only available from another source.

Package 'phpmyadmin' has no installation candidate
cyan@cyanonvo:~$
```

Comment: seemingly,the solution is found here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQPG_cOAi-g

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there's no `phpmyadmin` package in the Ubuntu 19.10 repositories. As you may know, Ubuntu is based on Debian. The person who used to build Debian packages of phpMyAdmin [doesn't have the time for it anymore](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15236), so there are no current `phpmyadmin` packages for Debian. And without current packages for Debian, (at least in this case) there are no current packages for Ubuntu.

Some people are working on `phpmyadmin` packages for Debian, and once those are finished, [they can be adapted for Ubuntu 19.10](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515).

So you can either wait until the volunteers for Debian and Ubuntu have created and tested those packages, or install phpMyAdmin with some other method. It's basically a PHP app, so you can just put it into a folder on a server where PHP gets executed. Or you use Composer, or...

Comment: Thank you for reply,I installed LTS which you don't face weird problems

Comment: Looking forward to having phpmyadmin in the main repo for Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1):

```
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.1/phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-english.tar.gz
tar xvzf phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-english.tar.gz
sudo cp -avr ./phpMyAdmin-4.9.1-english/. /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

I would use 18.04 and LTS Enablement for Mariadb and phpMyAdmin.  It is 5 year support LTS

Answer (score 1):

Forget about PhpMyAdmin in Ubuntu 19.10, there are 2 excellent alternatives:

- [Valentina Studio](https://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview).
- [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

I prefer Valentina Studio, it's more intuitive, but only because of this, doesn't mean that DBeaver isn't good.
Both of them have a .deb installation package, give them a try, you'll not regret.